# Spark key/value pair issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

How can I iterate through the values of a key which is suppose to have `Array[Array[String]]` . I have a key `k`, for which the values are in `Array[Array[String]]` format after reading the files using `sc.wholetextfiles`. How can I iterate through the values of each of the keys to read the values line by line

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need something like this:

```
textFilesData.values.map(doubleArray => doubleArray.flatten.map(line=> ...))
```

Although, we would need to know your exact data type to be sure, as your question is still a bit vague and could use a little more specifics for a better answer.